# uploading image to 000webhost.com via android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-volley

so im trying to connect my android studio to this web server (000webhost) but can't seem to upload it successfully, i think the problem is the path but i haven't found some examples online on how to connect to the file manager of the 000webhost

connection.php

```
header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_image"])){

    $encoded_image = $_POST["encoded_image"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_image);

    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path,'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file,$decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0){
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','id7794597_razzlesz','hahayz9090','id7794597_memes');
        $query = "INSERT INTO photos (name,path) values ('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if($result){
            echo "success";
            }else{
                echo "failed";
            }
            mysqli_close($connection);
    }
}
```

?>

btnUpload

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlUpload, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }

        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                String imageData = imageToString(bitmap);
                String imgName = edtName.getText().toString();
                params.put ("encoded_image", imageData);
                params.put ("image_name", imgName);

                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"image uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

[my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT6BR.png)

what should i put on the path of the php?

Comment: What does it mean that it "can't seem to upload successfully"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: add the code directly to question instead of screenshots

Comment: there's no error message, it just wont reflect to the db and file manager of that site

Answer (score 0):

His Problem seems to be the directory path. 000webhost has different directory path as what i have understood. If there is no error messages in the app then it must be the path directory for it is already at the online database.